# Mock CDI Injected class using Mockito on a JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, cdi

This is the method that i am trying to test:

```
@Singleton
public class PriorityJobQueueService {
    public void registerIndividualJob(String jobCode) throws InterruptedException {
        List<PriorityJobMapDTO> priorityJobMapDTOS = CDI.current().select(JobGroupsMasterService.class).get().getJobForCronScheduler(jobCode);
        priorityJobMapDTOS = validateStrictJobs(priorityJobMapDTOS);
        triggerJob(priorityJobMapDTOS);
    }
}
```

This is the skeleton structure of my test file:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PriorityJobQueueServiceTest {

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
        fixture = new Fixture();
    }

    @Test
    public void registerIndividualJob_SUCCESS() throws InterruptedException {

    }

    private class Fixture {
        @InjectMocks
        PriorityJobQueueService priorityJobQueueService;

        private Fixture() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what i need to do is mock **CDI.current.select()** statement so that i can run the test.

The only things i've found so far is having to add additional dependencies to my project with the following libraries:

- [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/blog/mocking/)
- [cdi-unit](https://github.com/cdi-unit/cdi-unit)

So are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, a few questions: (1) What kind of `@Singleton` is this, EJB or CDI? (2) In either case, why are you getting the `JobGroupsMasterService` through `CDI.current().select(...)` and not with normal injection, i.e. `@Inject JobGroupsMasterService`, or, even better, constructor injection? (3) If you are using CDI, why don't you embrace a testing framework for it, cdi-unit or weld-junit? (You don't need Quarkus just for testing) In order to mock `CDI.current()`, you need the testing framework (or do something unecessarilly dirty yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to be composable. That's the entire point of Dependency Injection :)

```
@Singleton
public class PriorityJobQueueService {
  @Inject
  private JobGroupsMasterService jobGroupsMasterService;

    public void registerIndividualJob(String jobCode) throws InterruptedException {
        List<PriorityJobMapDTO> priorityJobMapDTOS = jobGroupsMasterService.getJobForCronScheduler(jobCode);
        priorityJobMapDTOS = validateStrictJobs(priorityJobMapDTOS);
        triggerJob(priorityJobMapDTOS);
    }
}
```

Now your test will look like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class PriorityJobQueueServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private JobGroupsMasterService jobGroupsMasterService;
  @InjectMocks
  private PriorityJobQueueService priorityJobQueueService;

  @Test
  void registerIndividualJob_SUCCESS() throws InterruptedException {
    priorityJobQueueService.registerIndividualJob(...);
  }
}
```

cheers, good luck!